# ionic serve gives blank page

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I have some more questions. So I've tried many tutorials online, but whenever I try to ionic serve, it always displays a blank page in my browser. I googled and tried the solutions offered online, but they don't seem to be working. I'm not sure if there's something wrong with my ionic or just those tutorial, this is the tutorial i am currently following [here](https://remotestack.io/ionic-sqlite-database-crud-offline-mobile-app-tutorial/). Here is my ionic info, please let me know if you need more info. Thank you

> Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 6.2.0
> @angular-devkit/build-angular : 14.1.0    @angular-devkit/schematics
> : 14.1.0    @angular/cli                  : 14.1.0
> @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 6.1.0
>
> Cordova:
>
> Cordova CLI       : 11.0.0    Cordova Platforms : android 10.1.2
> Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0,
> cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0, (and 3 other plugins)
>
> Utility:
>
> cordova-res : 0.15.4    native-run  : 1.6.0
>
> System:
>
> NodeJS : v16.16.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)    npm    :
> 8.11.0    OS     : Windows 10

Comment: Please include your code.

Comment: which part of coding?

Comment: I answered your question and let me know if it is work or not.

Comment: after firing ionic serve, your browser window is blank. Right-click and inspect the console tab to get some clarity on the exact issue. if nothing gets flagged then there is a possible routing issue.

Answer (score -1):

First you need to add browser platform with the following command.

> ionic cordova platform add browser

And then, you can run with

> ionic cordova run browser